# MySQL - selecting members created by members

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the scenario. I have different levels of users. the user creation process is like this:
admin -> reseller -> marketer -> autoservice

I am trying to write a SQL query to select all autoservices created by a specific reseller. all users are saved in users table which has the following simplified structure:

```
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | userid | username     | role        | createdby |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 334455 | reseller1    | reseller    | admin     |
| 2  | 245578 | marketer1    | marketer    | reseller1 |
| 3  | 235677 | autoservice1 | autoservice | marketer1 |
| 4  | 253569 | autoservice2 | autoservice | marketer1 |
| 5  | 234267 | autoservice3 | autoservice | marketer1 |
| 6  | 245468 | marketer2    | marketer    | reseller1 |
| 5  | 434567 | autoservice4 | autoservice | marketer2 |
| 5  | 532263 | autoservice5 | autoservice | marketer2 |
| 5  | 634262 | autoservice6 | autoservice | marketer2 |
+----+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

The query should select autoservice1, autoservice2, autoservice3, autoservice4, autoservice5, autoservice6 and all their fields. currently I'm doing this with a combination of MySQL and php. First I select all marketers created by reseller1:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM marketers WHERE createdby=:createdby";
$st=$conn->prepare($sql);
$st->bindvalue(":createdby",'reseller1',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
$usersArray=$st->fetchAll();
$NumberOfusers=$st->rowcount();
```

Then I loop through the results:

```
$MembersGeoData=array();
$MembersCount=0;
for($i=0;$i<$NumberOfusers;$i++) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM autoservices WHERE createdby=:createdby";
    $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindvalue(":createdby",$usersArray[$i]['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->execute();
    $tempUsersArray=$st->fetchAll();
    $tempNumberOfusers=$st->rowcount();
    $MembersGeoData=array_merge($MembersGeoData,$tempUsersArray);
     $MembersCount+=$tempNumberOfusers;
}
```

This works but seems to be very inefficient. How can I do this with one sql query?

Comment: Can you please add the schematic of your tables? Do you have two tables named `marketers` and `autoservices`? if so, why don't you use the id of the _marketer_ in the `createdby` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used The answer from @Gordon Linoff and answered my question :

```
SELECT a.* FROM autoservices AS a 
JOIN marketers AS m
ON a.createdby=m.username
WHERE m.createdby='reseller1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your hierarchy is exactly correct (it is never skipped and a marketer never creates another marketer), then:

```
select sa.*
from autoservices sm join
     autoservices sa
     on sa.role = 'autoservice' and
        sm.role = 'marketer' and
        sm.username = sa.createdBy
where sm.createdBy = 'reseller1';
```

You are correct.  You should let the database do this work.

Comment: I am not good at sql. what are sm and sa? are they aliases? if so, shouldn't you use "as" keyword? or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @MehdiBagheri As you guessed they are aliases and it does not matter what name you pick for them. you can use anything for them, but it's better for you to use a name which make sense to you...

Comment: @MehdiBagheri . . . I always use `as` for column aliases, because two "names" next to each other can be misleading.  I never use them for table aliases, because the `as` doesn't add anything.